# NodeJS Referencing exports modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm having some issues referencing some dynamic variables which equate to some mongoose model based on user session location value. I have two scripts.

location.js & reporting.js

location.js

```
module.exports = function(req) {
// Setting some variables to do the following.
// Assign var to value of the client remote address. This should return the ip address.
// The remoteAddress object returns an IPV6 format. Because of this, I setup a new var to the value of the client IP stripped of the ":::ffff" portion.
// I then split the string by the period character to get an array of the sections of string.

var clientIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
var strippedIP = clientIP.replace(/^.*:/, '');
var splitIP = clientIP.split('.')

// Determining if the site session value based on second octet of ip response.
  if (splitIP[1] == '28') {
    req.session.site = 'shk';
  }
  else if (splitIP[1] == '29') {
    req.session.site = 'ftm';
  }
  else if (splitIP[1] == '31') {
    req.session.site = 'tpe';
  }
  else {
    req.session.site = 'ftm';
  }

// Using case statement to determine the machinery model to use as well as passdowns.

switch(req.session.site) {
  // Shakopee Variables
  case 'shk':
    console.log("You're located in Shakopee.");

    var Machinery = require('../models/machinery_shk');
    var Loggings = require('../models/passdowns_shk');

    break;
  // Fort Mill Variables
  case 'ftm':
    console.log("You're located in Fort Mill.");

    var Machinery = require('../models/machinery_ftm');
    var Loggings = require('../models/passdowns_ftm');

    break;
  // Tempe Variables
  case 'tpe':
    console.log("You're located in Tempe.");

    var Machinery = require('../models/machinery_tpe');
    var Loggings = require('../models/passdowns_tpe');

    break;
  // Default values to use if no case is matched.
  default:
    console.log("You're located in Default");

    var Machinery = require('../models/machinery_ftm');
    var Loggings = require('../models/passdowns_ftm');

    break;
}
};
```

reporting.js - route

```
  reportingRouter.route('/')

    .get((req, res, next) => {
      Location(req);

        if (req.session.loggedIn === false || req.session.loggedIn === undefined || !req.session.loggedIn) {
          res.redirect('/reporting/login')
        }
        else if (req.session.loggedIn === true) {

        Loggings.find({}, (err, loggings) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          else {
            Machinery.find({}, (err, machinery) => {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              else {
                // console.log(machinery)
                Shifts.find({}, (err, shifts) => {
                  if (err) {
                    throw err;
                  }
                  else {
                    res.render('reporting', { pageTitle: 'Reporting', loggings: loggings, machinery: machinery, shifts: shifts, ldapFullName: req.session.fullName })
                    // console.log(loggings)
                  }
                })
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

location.js is set up to expose a function taking one parameter. That parameter is to be the express `"req"` object. This script also takes the client IP Address. I take the client IP and get the second octet of the string.

Based on that value, I assign a property in the `session` object of the `req` object in express session.

```
req.session.site = <some-value>
```

Once that is set, I perform a switch case on that value assigned. If some value, assign more variables to certain mongoose models. For example, I set up a `"Loggings"` variable to a certain mongoose model.

```
var Loggings = require('../models/passdown_<site-id>')
```

Assuming those variables are assigned, I should be able to `"require"` this script inside of my reporting.js script.

Inside reporting.js, I assign a variable to that module.

```
var Location = require('location')
```

Then, I call that variable and pass in the `req` parameter when on some route. For example, when a `"GET"` is performed on some route, I call this `Location` module "function" passing in the `req` object.

```
Location(req)
```

Now, assuming all of this works, shouldn't I be able to perform a mongoose query referencing the `"Loggings"` variable I set up in location.js? I'm getting some `undefined` and I believe it's due to variable scope issues. In this instance, should I `"export"` those model requires? For example,

```
exports.Loggings = require('../models/passdown_<site-id>')
```

Apologies for my ignorance here.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I decided to throw location check logic into function under app.js. Added `next()` method to the end of function after location variables are determined. This way, after function runs, it will proceed to any awaiting routes.

Then I tell app to use this middleware function.

```
app.use(checkLocation);
```

This works for me and the app needs. Probably not the best solution, but I got it working using this. If anyone has any other input, I'm open to it.